SQLAlchemy 2.0 filtering multiple search terms across multiple many-to-many and one-to-many relationships?
What is an efficient query I can do to get all Item rows based on a list of include/exclude terms, with the text search also applying across the many-to-many and one-to-many relationships?
I'm trying to use SQLAlchemy 2.0 with its select().
An Example:
db = SQLAlchemy()


item_property1 = db.Table("item_property1",
    Column("item_id", Integer, ForeignKey("item.id"), primary_key=True),
    Column("property1_id", Integer, ForeignKey("property1.id"), primary_key=True)
)
item_property2 = db.Table("item_property2",
    Column("item_id", Integer, ForeignKey("item.id"), primary_key=True),
    Column("property2_id", Integer, ForeignKey("property2.id"), primary_key=True)
)
item_property3 = db.Table("item_property3",
    Column("item_id", Integer, ForeignKey("item.id"), primary_key=True),
    Column("property3_id", Integer, ForeignKey("property3.id"), primary_key=True)
)
item_property4 = db.Table("item_property4",
    Column("item_id", Integer, ForeignKey("item.id"), primary_key=True),
    Column("property4_id", Integer, ForeignKey("property4.id"), primary_key=True)
)


class Item(Model):
    __tablename__ = "item"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(Text)

    # One to Many
    category1_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("category1.id"))
    category2_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("category2.id"))

    # Many to Many
    properties1 = db.relationship('Property1', secondary=item_property1, lazy='subquery', backref=db.backref('items', lazy=True))
    properties2 = db.relationship('Property2', secondary=item_property2, lazy='subquery', backref=db.backref('items', lazy=True))
    properties3 = db.relationship('Property3', secondary=item_property3, lazy='subquery', backref=db.backref('items', lazy=True))
    properties4 = db.relationship('Property4', secondary=item_property4, lazy='subquery', backref=db.backref('items', lazy=True))


## Below Many-to-Many relationships
class Property1(Model):
    __tablename__ = "property1"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(Text)

class Property2(Model):
    __tablename__ = "property2"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(Text)

class Property3(Model):
    __tablename__ = "property3"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(Text)

class Property4(Model):
    __tablename__ = "property4"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(Text)


## Below are One-to-Many relationships
class Category1(Model):
    __tablename__ = "category1"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(Text)
    items = db.relationship("Item", backref="category1", lazy=True)

class Category2(Model):
    __tablename__ = "category2"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(Text)
    items = db.relationship("Item", backref="category2", lazy=True)

I want to search an Item's direct name, it's many-to-many fields: property1.name, property2.name, property3.name, property4.name, and it's one-to-many fields:  category1.name, category2.name. If ANY of the terms I'm searching for matches, then I want that Item. This must be an OR relationship since I want any Item that contains those specific terms. The Items returned should be distinct (no duplicate or repeat Item).
ie, something like this:
# Search Terms
include_terms = ["%bob%", "%alice%", "%eve%"]
exclude_terms = ["%abc%", "%profanity1%, "%nope%"]

# Filter for include_terms first
one = SELECT * FROM Item WHERE name LIKE ANY(include_terms) OR
                         property1.name LIKE ANY(include_terms) OR
                         property2.name LIKE ANY(include_terms) OR
                         property3.name LIKE ANY(include_terms) OR
                         property4.name LIKE ANY(include_terms) OR
                         category1.name LIKE ANY(include_terms) OR
                         category2.name LIKE ANY(include_terms)

# Then filter OUT ones that match ANY of the exclude_terms
two = SELECT * FROM one where name NOT LIKE ANY(exclude_terms) OR
                         property1.name NOT LIKE ANY(exclude_terms) OR
                         property2.name NOT LIKE ANY(exclude_terms) OR
                         property3.name NOT LIKE ANY(exclude_terms) OR
                         property4.name NOT LIKE ANY(exclude_terms) OR
                         category1.name NOT LIKE ANY(exclude_terms) OR
                         category2.name NOT LIKE ANY(exclude_terms)


# Return all unique Items, with no duplicates
return two.distinct() 

I've tried the following, and it sort of works, but it's returning the wrong number of items, and the count is wildly huge sometimes (like 200k items when it should be just 2 items). I think it's looping again and again and grabbing the same item? A lot of times nothing gets returned even though there are definitely terms that match:
    # Filter for include_terms

    items = db.select(Item) \
              .join(Item.properties1) \
              .join(Item.properties2) \
              .join(Item.properties3) \
              .join(Item.properties4) \
              .join(Category1) \
              .join(Category2) \
              .filter(or_( \
                    *[Item.name.like(term) for term in include_terms], \
                    *[Property1.name.like(term) for term in include_terms], \
                    *[Property2.name.like(term) for term in include_terms], \
                    *[Property3.name.like(term) for term in include_terms], \
                    *[Property4.name.like(term) for term in include_terms], \
                    *[Category1.name.like(term) for term in include_terms], \
                    *[Category2.name.like(term) for term in include_terms]
    )))


    # Filter out exclude_terms
    items.filter(or_( \
                    *[Item.name.notlike(term) for term in exclude_terms], \
                    *[Property1.name.notlike(term) for term in exclude_terms], \
                    *[Property2.name.notlike(term) for term in exclude_terms], \
                    *[Property3.name.notlike(term) for term in exclude_terms], \
                    *[Property4.name.notlike(term) for term in exclude_terms], \
                    *[Category1.name.notlike(term) for term in exclude_terms], \
                    *[Category2.name.notlike(term) for term in exclude_terms]
    ))

    # no dupes
    return items.distinct()

What would be the correct (and more efficient) way of doing this?
